# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using a third party .jar file

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using NetBeans. I have a simple project, which prints in a fancy format some data sent as arguments.
This is the code that throws an Exception:

```
        JasperDesign design =  JRXmlLoader.load("Certificate.jrxml");
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap(), new ClientList(args).getClients());
        JPanel panel= new JRViewer(print);
```

These Exceptions are thrown whenever a Jasper class is created.
I also tried System.getProperty("java.class.path") and it includes the "jasperreports-5.0.1.jar" file..
What am I doing wrong? I know these Exceptions are thrown whenever a class is available at compile time, but not at runtime.. But the jar is there!

Requested Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester

at certificado.Certificado.main(Certificado.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)

... 1 more

Java Result: 1
```

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be compiling against the Jasper jar ok, but at runtime that jar has its own dependencies, and you should include those too.

According to your stacktrace you need [Apache Commons Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/). I would perhaps build using Maven, and let Maven (hopefully) resolve the set of dependencies for you. You *can* use a [Jar search engine](http://www.findjar.com) to find these dependencies, but they won't determine matching versions of those jars for you.

Comment: I'm trying this ! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I *suspect* you'll find a couple more jar files missing, but the above gives you enough info to resolve this, hopefully

Comment: It does! Thanks a lot !! I have a 2 day deadline and I just started developing using java

Answer (score 1):

Your library (Jasper?) seems to have a (run-time) dependency on another library.
Meaning, it requires some other JAR to be present on classpath when being executed.

The missing classname is `org/apache/commons/digester/Digester`. Thus you can guess the missing library is [`commons-digester`](http://commons.apache.org/digester/). Make sure the Digester library is available on Classpath too.

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem, I just add ***commons-digester-2.0.jar*** and problem get solved.