# NoClassDefFoundError when creating dynamic jasper report

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to create a dynamic jasper report. So I tried creating one using an example in the internet. But when I run the program I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/digester/Digester  at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:143)
>     at com.tfc.cheque.handle.ui.ReportPrint.main(ReportPrint.java:31)

given below is the code I used:

```
public class ReportPrint {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, IOException {

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("data.xml");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "sample.pdf");

  }

public ReportPrint(){

    try {
        DynamicReportBuilder dynamicReportBuilder = new DynamicReportBuilder();

        // configure report-level settings
        dynamicReportBuilder.setReportName("Some");

        dynamicReportBuilder.setPageSizeAndOrientation(Page.Page_Letter_Landscape());

        // add id column to the report
        ColumnBuilder columnBuilderID = ColumnBuilder.getNew();

        columnBuilderID.setTitle("ID");
        columnBuilderID.setWidth(180);
        columnBuilderID.setFixedWidth(true);
        columnBuilderID.setColumnProperty("ID", Integer.class.getName(), "@id");

        dynamicReportBuilder.addColumn(columnBuilderID.build());

        // add name column to report
        ColumnBuilder columnBuilderName = ColumnBuilder.getNew();

        columnBuilderName.setTitle("Name");
        columnBuilderName.setWidth(180);
        columnBuilderName.setFixedWidth(true);
        columnBuilderName.setColumnProperty("Name", String.class.getName(), "@name");

        dynamicReportBuilder.addColumn(columnBuilderName.build());

        // add email column to report
        ColumnBuilder columnBuilderEmail = ColumnBuilder.getNew();

        columnBuilderEmail.setTitle("Email");
        columnBuilderEmail.setWidth(180);
        columnBuilderEmail.setFixedWidth(true);
        columnBuilderEmail.setColumnProperty("Email", String.class.getName(),   "@email");

        dynamicReportBuilder.addColumn(columnBuilderEmail.build());

        // add salary column to report
        ColumnBuilder columnBuilderSalary = ColumnBuilder.getNew();

        columnBuilderSalary.setTitle("Salary");
        columnBuilderSalary.setWidth(180);
        columnBuilderSalary.setFixedWidth(true);
        columnBuilderSalary.setColumnProperty("Salary", Integer.class.getName(), "@salary");

        dynamicReportBuilder.addColumn(columnBuilderSalary.build());

        DynamicReport dynamicReport = dynamicReportBuilder.build();

        // build a datasource representing the XML file
        JRDataSource dataSource = new JRXmlDataSource(new File("data.xml"), "//employee");

        // build JasperPrint instance, filling the report with data from datasource created above
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(
            dynamicReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), dataSource, new HashMap<String, Object>());

        // export to the pdf
        String pdfFile = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000) + ".pdf";

        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, pdfFile);

        exporter.exportReport();

    } catch(JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

I cannot Figure out the problem here. Please help. Thank you.

Here's a screenshot of my class path settings:

[image: Class path screen shot]

Comment: you need Apache Common Digester.

See other similiar [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-a-third-party-jar-file

Comment: Thank you very much. I add the jar file. but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the file `commons-digester.jar` is missing in your classpath. [Download](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/download_digester.cgi) it and add it to the classpath.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I added commons-digester.jar. But the same problem occurs.

Comment: @user3778655 can you show how you start the program?

Comment: I right click on the class and click run as "java application"

Comment: @user3778655 and it is really the same? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester ` r is it an other class?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your classpath settings?

Comment: @Jens I've added the screenshot in my post. Could you look at it?

Comment: @user3778655 You do not need the version 3 of commons-digester, you need the version 2. You can download it [here](http://artfiles.org/apache.org//commons/digester/binaries/). In version 3 the package was changed to digester3.

Comment: Now I have another problem. It gives this exception:

Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:176)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:143)
 at com.tfc.cheque.handle.ui.ReportPrint.main(ReportPrint.java:31)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.xml

Comment: I added the xml file. But doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @user3778655 looks like your `data.xml` file will not be found. where is it in your project structure?

Comment: It's inside the same package as the above class.

Comment: then try JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ReportPrint.class.getResourceAsStream("data.xml"));

Comment: It is not working either. When I use the above solution it gives the NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Comment: Which class is not found?

Comment: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Comment: You have to add the [commons-logging.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) and add it to your classpath.

Comment: There are several other jar files are missing. I am adding one by one now. Is there any problem if the versions of those files are different from each other?

Comment: @user3778655 In general not. But if one jar needs a specific version of an other it can bring some problems.

Comment: I am really sorry for troubling you with so many questions. I got another exception

{Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:251)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:230)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:196)
 at com.tfc.cheque.handle.ui.ReportPrint.main(ReportPrint.java:31)}

Comment: Which version of jasperreport do you use?

Comment: jasperreport 4.1 and Dynamicjasper 4.0

Comment: can you add the Line, where you call `JasperCompileManager.compileReport`

Comment: JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ReportPrint.class.getResourceAsStream("data.x‌​ml"));

Comment: I'll try to add a new xml file. Thank you very much.